# Very weird tracking of a file using git

Tags: git

using git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1 a file is somehow weirdly tracked. What may be the reason?

I have a file named *missingFile* in git.

```
$ ls
missingFile

$ git add missingFile

$ git status
# On branch test
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git commit missingFile
# On branch test
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Now I delete this file. Git does not miss it. That makes me wonder.

```
$ rm missingFile

$ ls

$ git status
# On branch test
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git commit
# On branch test
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

However, when checking out the file it magically reappears again.

```
$ git checkout missingFile

$ ls
missingFile
```

And also the diff reveals the file.

```
$ git diff origin/master
diff --git a/missingFile b/missingFile
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..0633ff0
--- /dev/null
+++ b/missingFile
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+missingFile_content
```

How can I get the standard behaviour (recognizing the deleted file, committing the removal, adding the file) for that file again?

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into your question or add the word "[Solved]" to the title. Instead, post it as an answer and (optionally) accept it. (Yes, it's perfectly acceptable to post an answer to your own question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

The file had the *skip-worktree* property. This was revealed by the leading **S** in

```
$ git ls-files -v
S missingFile
```

And a simple call to `git update-index --no-skip-worktree` had the desired effect:

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree missingFile
$ git status
# On branch test
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   missingFile
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```